# javascript variable assignment core

Tags: javascript

suppose i have this

```
var x={};    //x is an address in the memory where object is stored
var z=x;     //z=x after execution is equal to z={} right?
```

now z has nothing to do with x or not related to x after execution so when,

```
x={name:"Maizere"};
z!=x        //true
```

but, when

```
x.name="maizere";
alert(z.name)//maizere why?
```

we are not setting the value of z but x and  z relation to x shouldn't exit anymore

actual code:

```
 x={};
 y=x;
 x.name="maizere";
 alert(y.name)//maizere
```

I really have no knowledge of how this is working .Can anyone explain this in detail please?

Comment: `alert(z.name) -> undefined` ... you missed something.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined`. Please show us your exact code, and use comments properly.

Comment: @Bergi  no u did some mistake ,u get "Maizere" .Check the code u tested plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial assumption is wrong; `z` is a pointer to the same object as `x`.

```
var x = {}; 
var z = x;

alert( z === x );    // true
```

When you do `x = { name: "Maizere" };` you're assigning a *new* object to `x`. `z` is still pointing to the *original* object.

```
x = { name: "Maizere" };
alert( z !== x );    // true
```

In the latter example you're not creating a new object but changing the original object's property.

```
var x = {}; 
var z = x;

x.name = "maizere";
alert( z === x );    // true
```

A further example of where the confusion might stem from: the bracket syntax creates a new object instead of modifying the original.

```
var x = { name: "Maizere" };
var y = { name: "Zaimere" };

x = { age: 20 };
y.age = 30;

console.log( x );  // {age: 20}                  <-- original object is replaced
console.log( y );  // {name: "Zaimere", age: 30} <-- original object is modified
```

Comment: according to u if x={} and z={} x==z //true so if x.name="maizere" will z have the property "name"

Comment: No. The objects are equal, but not the *same* object. If you change one of them they're not equal anymore.  (Just like if you have `x=1; z=1; x==z // true` but if you change `z=2` then `x != z`.)

Answer (score 3):

After these two statements:

```
x={};
y=x;
```

The internal representation is like this:

```
      +---- x
      |
{} <--+
      |
      +---- y
```

So any changes to `x` are reflected in `y`:

```
 x.name="maizere";
 alert(y.name)//maizere
```

Updated:

```
                     +---- x
                     |
{name: 'maizere'} <--+
                     |
                     +---- y
```

This goes away once you assign either variable to something else:

```
x = { name: "Maizere" }
```

Representation:

```
{name: 'Maizere'} <------- x

{name: 'maizere'} <------- y
```

Comment: but what if i  do x = { name: "Maizere" }; after z value is set

Comment: That creates a new object and changes `x` to point to it, it has no effect on `z`.

Comment: @MaizerePathak I've updated the answer with what I think you meant with the comment, let me know if that makes sense.